# How to delete rows in VBA using targeted range

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet and I need to delete rows starting from A3:M3. All rows below him should also be deleted. I'm using the code below and the entire rows now are empty.

Any tips and tricks how to do it?

```
For i = 3 To 10
    rws = "A" & i & ":" & "M" & i
    Range(rws).EntireRow.Delete
Next
```

Comment: You want delete row from A until last row such as 1000, or you just want to delete certain row? You code seem fine to me

Comment: You should iterate backwards. But, why iteration? If you want only learning, it may be OK. You can delete them, if no condition applied, at once, for all the rows...

Comment: @KinSiang yah i want to delete the rows from A3 below

Comment: @FaneDuru I've set last_row = data_sheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row - 1 then the loop but it doesn't delete all below it . I don't know how to do it yet

Comment: Like I said, iterating backwards (from 10 to 3) it will work. Otherwise, the range reference is lost by deletion... But you can do it at once, without iteration. I posted a piece of code. And, please learn that it is good to **always** declare all used variables...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try the next code:

```
Sub deleteRowsOver3()
   Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long
   
   Set sh = ActiveSheet
   lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
   sh.Range("A3:A" & lastR).EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```